# Применить Java-аннотацию только к полю определенного типа

Tags: java, рефлексия, аннотации

Хочу написать аннотацию, которую можно применять только к полям определенного типа, например, `org.rethinkdb.net.Connection`.

Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для этого понадобиться написать процессор аннотаций, который на этапе компиляции будет проверять тип аннотированного поля.

**SomeAnnotation.java**

```
package com.example;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface SomeAnnotation {}
```

**SomeProcessor.java**

```
package com.example;

import java.util.Set;

import javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor;
import javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedAnnotationTypes;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedSourceVersion;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedOptions;
import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
import javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement;
import javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror;
import javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind;
import javax.lang.model.util.Elements;
import javax.lang.model.util.Types;
import javax.tools.Diagnostic;

import org.rethinkdb.net.Connection;

@SupportedAnnotationTypes("com.example.SomeAnnotation")
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_8)
public class SomeProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        if (roundEnv.processingOver())
            return false;

        Elements elements = processingEnv.getElementUtils();
        Types types = processingEnv.getTypeUtils();
        TypeMirror expected = elements.getTypeElement(Connection.class.getCanonicalName())
                                      .asType();

        for (Element element : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(SomeAnnotation.class)) {
            TypeMirror type = element.asType();
            if (!types.isSameType(type, expected))
                processingEnv.getMessager()
                             .printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR, "Invalid type!", element);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**build\META-INF\services\javax.annotation.processing.Processor**

```
com.example.SomeProcessor
```

Компилируем аннотацию и процессор

```
javac -cp "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\lib\tools.jar";rethinkdb-0.10.1.jar -d build SomeAnnotation.java SomeProcessor.java
```

Упаковываем в jar

```
jar cf someprocessor.jar -C build .
```

**Example.java**

```
import com.example.SomeAnnotation;
import org.rethinkdb.net.Connection;

public class Example {
    @SomeAnnotation
    private boolean someField;
    //private Connection connection;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

Пробуем скомпилировать пример

```
javac -cp someprocessor.jar;rethinkdb-0.10.1.jar Example.java
```

И получаем

```
Example.java:5: error: Invalid type!
    private boolean someField;
                    ^
1 error
```